# Se puede este tipo de consulta

Tags: sql, select

Quisiera que seleccionara los datos según los parámetros y según el `type_user`.

```
$query = "SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user 
from users 
where id_user = ? AND password_user= ? and type_user = 'admin' or type_user ='receipt' or type_user = 'output'";
```

Asi es como estoy poniendo los parámetros, si cambiara el parámetro de `type_user` por `admin`, solo me mostraría  ese ya que el `id_user` que también le mando es único

```
http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/user.php?id_user=56012 & password_user=123& type_user=receipt
```

Al imprimir los resultados de esta manera, y poner parametros en postman, me marca el siguiente error.

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\apis\user.php** on line **23**

Y mas abajo aparece asi:

```
{"status":0,"user":{"id_user":null,"password_user":null,"type_user":null}}

  if ($result>0)
    {
      $user = json_encode(array(
                'id_user' => $result[0][0],
                'password_user' => $result[0][1],
                'type_user' => $result[0][2]
              ));
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'user' => json_decode($user)
        ));
    }//if
```

Antes lo tenia de esta manera:

```
  $query = "SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user from users where id_user = ? AND password_user= ? and type_user =  ?";
```

Le ponia el parámetro admin, receipt etc, y me mostraba los datos sin ningún problema,quisiera hacerlo de esta manera ya que lo ocupo para otra parte que estoy haciendo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es en sí el problema?

Comment: Me parece que accedes mal a `$result` para crear los datos de `$user`... ¿podrías mostrar un `var_dump($result);`? Y de ser posible muestra también cómo estás llenando `$result`

Comment: Sin tener que ver con el error, creo que la consulta es errónea, debes poner los `OR` entre paréntesis o te sacara todos los `type_user` sin tener en cuenta  `id_user` ni `password`: SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user 
from users 
where id_user = ? AND password_user= ? and **( type_user = 'admin' or type_user ='receipt' or type_user = 'output' )**

Comment: Me salta este error syntax error, unexpected '$result'

Comment: $result parace ser un objeto o array asociativo y tu intentas acceder a el como un array indexado, por eso te da error de indice sin definir (`Notice: Undefined offset: 0 ...`)